# Ordinal identifier issue - QTP

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

There are 4 static text on page

```
jWin.JavataStaticText("toolkit class:=nz.vdi","index:=0").GetROProperty("attached text")
jWin.JavataStaticText("toolkit class:=nz.vdi","index:=1").GetROProperty("attached text")
jWin.JavataStaticText("toolkit class:=nz.vdi","index:=2").GetROProperty("attached text")
jWin.JavataStaticText("toolkit class:=nz.vdi","index:=3").GetROProperty("attached text")
```

When I run this script then I get output in following way

```
VM
Host
Host Server
Storage Volume
```

When I run the same script after 4-5 mins then I output sequence get changed

```
Host Server
VM
Storage Volume
Host
```

Why is it happening? Due to this problem I am not able to perform expected task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Index** selector is the last fall-back that UFT uses when it can't uniquely identify an object. If you have a better way to identify the object (e.g. by using the *"attached text"* property) you should used that.

Basically what **Index** means is *"from the set of objects described by this description return the Nth one"* so if UFT gets the objects in a different order you will get different objects for the same **Index**.

I'm not familiar with Java so I don't know what order the objects are returned. Also I don't know what your use-case is but I'm pretty sure you can find a better way to verify your conditions.

One thing that may be helpful is using the **Location** selection property which depends on the relative location of the objects and may be more consistent in your case. The **location** selector orders objects first by their `x` coordinate and then by `y`.

```
For i = 0 to 3
  jWin.JavataStaticText("toolkit class:=nz.vdi","Location:=" & i).GetROProperty("attached text")
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...It works using Location...Now I am able to do my expected task.... Once again thanks

Comment: @onkar, if this answered your question you may consider marking the answer as accepted (by clicking the check mark) this will let people know that the question is answered.

Comment: Sorry Moti..I didnt know this...I have clicked Check mark
Thanks